Context state not setting properly in React
The title may be ambiguous but I am having a issue that redirects me to /home after I render the component assigned to /logout, whose job is to clear the storage and reset the AuthContext states. I could not come up with a minimal reproducible example so here's all of the code
Here's my project structure.
$ tree -I node_modules src
src
├── App.tsx
├── components
│   ├── ContentCenteredDiv.tsx
│   ├── Home.tsx
│   ├── Logout.tsx
│   ├── NavBar.tsx
│   ├── Typewriter.tsx
│   └── ui
│       ├── button.tsx
│       ├── form.tsx
│       ├── input.tsx
│       └── label.tsx
├── contexts
│   └── AuthProvider.tsx
├── hooks
│   └── useAuth.tsx
├── index.css
├── layouts
│   └── get-started
│       ├── GetStartedLayout.tsx
│       ├── Login.tsx
│       └── Register.tsx
├── lib
│   ├── constants.ts
│   ├── schema.ts
│   ├── types.ts
│   └── utils.ts
├── main.tsx
├── vite-env.d.ts
└── wrappers
    └── ProtectedRoute.tsx

9 directories, 23 files


I am using react-router for setting up the navigation routes. Here's my main.tsx
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Navigate,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./layouts/get-started/Login.tsx";
import GetStartedLayout from "./layouts/get-started/GetStartedLayout.tsx";
import Register from "./layouts/get-started/Register.tsx";
import AuthProvider from "./contexts/AuthProvider.tsx";
import ProtectedRoute from "./wrappers/ProtectedRoute.tsx";
import Logout from "./components/Logout.tsx";
import useAuth from "./hooks/useAuth.tsx";
import Home from "@/components/Home.tsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    // path: "/",
    index: true,
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "get-started",
    element: <GetStartedLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Navigate to="/get-started/login" />,
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "register",
        element: <Register />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "home",
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <Home />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "logout",
    element: <Logout />,
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
);


Here's the AuthProvider.tsx that contains the authentication details for current user.
import { SERVER_URL } from "@/lib/constants";
import { makePayload } from "@/lib/utils";
import { createContext, PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type AuthContextType = {
  checking: boolean;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  userId: number;
  setUserId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
  jwt: string;
  setJwt: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const def: AuthContextType = {
  checking: true,
  loggedIn: false,
  setLoggedIn: () => {},
  userId: -1,
  setUserId: () => {},
  jwt: "",
  setJwt: () => {},
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(def);

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(def.loggedIn);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(def.userId);
  const [jwt, setJwt] = useState(localStorage.getItem("jwt") || "");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `AuthContext inside useEffect(): checking: ${checking}, loggedIn: ${loggedIn}, userId: ${userId}, jwt:`, // ${jwt}`,
    );

    if (!jwt) {
      setChecking(false);
      return;
    }

    const url = `${SERVER_URL}/api/auth`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` },
    })
      .then((res) => makePayload(res))
      .then((payload) => {
        if (payload.ok) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
          setUserId(payload.userId);
        } else {
          throw `Authorization check failed: ${payload.message || "Unknown error"}`;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error fetching ${url}: ${err}`))
      .finally(() => setChecking(false));

  }, []);

  // Store jwt to localstorage when set
  useEffect(() => localStorage.setItem("jwt", jwt), [jwt]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        checking,
        loggedIn,
        setLoggedIn,
        userId,
        setUserId,
        jwt,
        setJwt,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

Here's the useAuth.tsx which is just a simple wrapper for useContext
import { AuthContext } from "@/contexts/AuthProvider";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function useAuth() {
  const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!ctx) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }

  return ctx;
}

Here's the App.tsx which handles redirection based on authentication status.
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useAuth from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ContentCenteredDiv from "@/components/ContentCenteredDiv";

export default function App() {
  const { loggedIn, checking } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      sessionStorage.clear();
    };
  }, []);

  if (checking) return <ContentCenteredDiv>Loading...</ContentCenteredDiv>;

  return <Navigate to={loggedIn ? "/home" : "/get-started"} />;
}

Below is the component that maps to the route /get-started/login
import { createElement, useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import { SERVER_URL } from "@/lib/constants";
import { makePayload } from "@/lib/utils";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginSchema } from "@/lib/schema";

const formSchema = z.object({
  username: loginSchema.username,
  password: loginSchema.password,
});

export default function Login() {
  const [err, setErr] = useState("");
  const [requesting, setRequesting] = useState(false);
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);

  const { setUserId, loggedIn, setLoggedIn, setJwt, jwt } = useAuth();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  
  // Login handler sets proper AuthContext states after successful login
  function loginHandler({ username, password }: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    setRequesting(true);
    setErr("");
    const url = `${SERVER_URL}/api/login`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    })
      .then((res) => makePayload(res))
      .then((payload) => {
        if (payload.ok) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
          setUserId(payload.userId as number);
          setJwt(payload.jwt);
        } else {
          setErr(payload.message);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error fetching ${url}: ${err}`))
      .finally(() => setRequesting(false));
  }

  if (loggedIn) return <Navigate to="/" />;

  return (
    // form (is long so I removed it)
  )
}

And finally Logout.tsx mapping to /logout and Home.tsx mapping to /home.
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";

export default function Logout() {
  const { setLoggedIn, setUserId, checking, loggedIn, userId, setJwt, jwt } =
    useAuth();

  // Reset all states and clear storage
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      `AuthContext during logout: checking: ${checking}, loggedIn: ${loggedIn}, userId: ${userId}, jwt: ${jwt}`,
    );
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    setLoggedIn(false);
    setUserId(-1);
    setJwt("");
    console.log("loggedout");
  }, []);

  return <Navigate to="/get-started" />;
}

import useAuth from "@/hooks/useAuth";

export default function Home() {
  const { setLoggedIn, setUserId, checking, loggedIn, userId, jwt } = useAuth();
  console.log(
    `AuthContext while loading home: checking: ${checking}, loggedIn: ${loggedIn}, userId: ${userId}, jwt: ${jwt}`,
  );
  return "HOME";
}

When I first open / I get redirected to /get-started/login. After I login, the states are set and I get redirected to /home. Now when I edit the url bar and replace http://localhost:5173/home to http://localhost:5173/logout, the login page flashes and I again get redirected to /home. (Expected to be at /get-started/login)
During this /logout -> /get-started/login -> /home, my backend also receives a auth request, meaning the useEffect() inside the AuthProvider ran again. The fetch request sends a valid jwt token to the server. How is this possible when I setJwt("") in Logout? How do I fix this issue?
Video.
Sandboxes:
Frontend: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xwayw6
Hardcoded Backend: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/serene-williams-p8mz44

I can follow the mounting logic up to Login navigating to "/", but App shouldn't navigate to "/home" yet because checking should still be true at this point in time. Do you have any other code elsewhere navigating to "/home"? How is that fetch call in the auth provider resolving? Is it possibly returning a cached value to the app? Think you could create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

@DrewReese I have dumped all of my code in the sandbox, I have edited the post and have included links. You can have a lokk

Issue
When the URL is manually updated it reloads the page, e.g. the entire React app. The Logout component renders the redirect to "/get-started" on the initial render and the effect doesn't execute until the end of the render cycle. By this point in time the AuthProvider  component has also already mounted and run its side-effect to check the auth status.
Solution
TL;DR Reason
The TL;DR is that the navigation from the "/logout" to "/get-started" happens prior to the Logout component's useEffect hook callback executing, so all the auth logic is looking at the current stored JWT token data before the Logout effect has cleared it out.
Suggestion to Fix
You should delay the logout navigation to occur at least one render cycle after the enqueued state updates for setLoggedIn, setUserId, and setJwt have had a chance to be processed by React and a rerender triggered so the auth flows can run and read the updated states and local and session storage values.
The trivial solution is to use a setTimeout with the shortest delay possible, which is enough to place the timeout callback at the end of the Javascript event loop and allow React to update.
Example:
Logout.tsx
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Logout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { setLoggedIn, setUserId, setJwt } = useAuth();

  // Reset all states and clear storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();

    // Enqueue React state updates
    setLoggedIn(false);
    setUserId(-1);
    setJwt("");

    // Place callback to end of event loop to navigate after
    // React updates are processed
    setTimeout(() => navigate("/get-started"), 0);
  }, []);

  // Return & render anything really, anything but Navigate
  return <div>Logging out...</div>;
};

Non-TL;DR Explanation
This is a basic/rough run-down of events as I'm able to track through them:

Manually update URL path to "/logout" and the page is reloaded

The React app mounts

AuthProvider mounts & renders

jwt state is initialized from localStorage
loggedIn is initially false


Path "/logout" is matched and Logout mounts & renders

Logout renders <Navigate to="/get-started" /> to navigate to "/get-started" route
"/get-started" route renders <Navigate to="/get-started/login" />
"/get-started/login" and Login is rendered.


I think roughly here both the effects in Login and AuthProvider execute. AuthProvider's effect uses the initial jwt state for the auth check and updates the loggedIn state. Logout's effect clears the storage and enqueues state updates.

Login renders if (loggedIn) return <Navigate to="/" />; and navigates to "/" because loggedIn is true after the AuthProvider auth API call resolves

Path "/" renders App and since loggedIn is true, <Navigate to="/home" /> is rendered and the UI navigates and renders the Home component.



That doesnot work at all, I thought of this being a time issue and had used a setTimeout inside the useEffect() that would set a state variable shouldNavigate to true and then only navigate.

I just added links to sandboxes. Everything else in the post is same.

@Diwas10 Here's the CodeSandbox demo I used to verify the behavior you described with the fix I've suggested here.

@Diwas10 Ok, FWIW the issue still occurs in your Stackblitz, even with the solution I've suggested applied. I will continue digging.
